# Pycharm cannot toggle sticky selection

Tags: pycharm, editor, selection, ubuntu-17.10

Somehow I enabled a selection mode in pycharm (community edition running on Ubuntu 17-10) that I can't disable. After some reading I suspect it's the "sticky selection mode", but toggling it doesn't make a difference. Here's what happens:

I single click on any location on the editor and release the button, then move the mouse, everything between the first click location and the current mouse position gets selected. To be clear, I don't keep the button pressed, a single click starts the selection.

I'd appreciate your help to first correctly identify which selection mode is this and then disable it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After a painful troubleshooting, I found that it was due to my system. For some reason my mouse clicks remained persistent. It was replicable using other applications to. A reboot resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me quite frequently, due to a bug with my touchscreen. If you touch the screen again it should fix the issue, it's not related to PyCharm (I went through this same process).

I have an Acer Aspire R14 running Ubuntu 18-04